# Adding webparts into content areas

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-online, template

By default in Sharepoint 2010, new pages I create have a really rich editing experience, allowing the user to add formatted text and webparts into the same content area e.g. [default page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV8cL.png).  These pages are 'Wiki pages' and get stored in the Site Pages library.

Having now enabled publishing mode so as to create a branded template for our pages (with fixed column widths and the like), it seems like the control being used for the content area is different - only allowing content to be placed in web part areas e.g. [new template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64fDW.png).  These pages are 'published pages' and get stored in the pages folder.

http://nikspatel.wordpress.com/2012/06/08/wiki-pages-vs-web-part-pages-for-sharepoint-intranet-content-pages/

We really want to use a blend of the two.  The published page gives lots of control over column widths etch that we don't seem to get from the wiki pages but the wiki page editor is much better.  Is there any way to use the same control that's being used on the wiki page in a published page?

Comment: To my knowledge there isn't any difference. It's the same RTE. Could you show us your HTML of the control in question?

Comment: I just did a bit more reading and will update my question in a sec but what I mean by default pages is the Wiki pages you get with a team site template.  The new template is a published page and gets a different control.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. I haven't tried this myself, but I would suggest that you try copying the control from the Wiki page into your publishing page to see if that would work. This can be done by using SharePoint Designer.

Comment: That didn't work but I did find a site template that kinda gets where we want to be.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new site collection using the Enterprise Wiki template has given me a site that has the wiki style editor as well as an editable page template.